# Is there a way to modify the function of an argument after it has already been specified in Python?

Tags: python, function, parameters, typeerror, callable

I'm working with ML regression algorithms, and I'd like to know if there is a way to state a function with specific arguments, and then add extra arguments to those already specified in another line of code. For example, for a random forest regressor I'd like to be able to turn bootstrapping on and then specify my maximum depth as follows:

```
funcy = RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap = True)
funcy(max_depth = 9)
```

However, doing this, I get a `TypeError` telling me that the Regressor object is not callable. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the class. You *may* or may not be able to do something like `funcy.max_depth = 9`, or use some other class-specific way to do that.

Comment: See [**`__call__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: You need to understand that second line **does not**  `add extra arguments`, it tries to EXECUTE `funcy` object with specific parameter, while first line instanciate an object with parameters

Comment: @azro, is there a way to add extra arguments?

Comment: Why don't you add them on first line ? If not you can MODIFY them with like `funcy.max_depth = false`

Comment: @deceze this worked! Thank you very much. Not 100% that I can use it for what I wanted to but nevertheless, your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @azro I'm using a loop to specify my discrete hyperparameters, and then using a whale algorithm to optimise my continuous ones.

Comment: Note that `funcy.max_depth = ...` probably won't throw an *error*, please don't take that to mean that it "worked", as in, that it actually influenced the object's behaviour. You should consult the documentation whether this is how you're supposed to do it.